# React Algolia InstantSearch - Is it possible to add a daterange?

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

I'm reading through the documentation for [React InstantSearch](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/) for my project and one thing I'm having trouble finding is a way to add a date-range to sort my list of hits. Has anyone had any luck in doing this? Let's say I have a field `createdAt` with a value `2017-11-08T09:19:46.310Z` and another field `createdAt` with a value `2017-11-10T09:19:46.310Z`. Is there a way I can get the results between those two dates?

Thanks in advance!

Update: I've tried adding the `<Configure />` code like the following:

```
<InstantSearch
    appId={'appId'}
    apiKey={'my-api-key'}
    indexName={'storeName'}
>
   <Configure filters="createdAt: 1503406467899 TO 1509950548555" />
   <SearchHit user={this.props.user} />
</InstantSearch>
```

And now I'm getting this error and my list is no longer loading:

```
warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `searchForItems` was not specified in RefinementList. in RefinementList (at translatable.js:22)
```

Could this be related to an outdated React Instant Search?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by first translating your string dates to timestamps and then using the [Configure widget](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/widgets/Configure.html) you could do:

```
<Configure filters="createdAt: 1511184231 TO 1511185231" />
```

(fictional timestamps)

Comment: Hey thanks for getting me in the right direction! I tried that with real timestamps from my data, but now I'm just getting an error when I add that `<Configure>` code. I've updated my question to account for this. Any thoughts?

Comment: I should note that I tried with `<Configure hitsPerPage={10} />` and that worked just fine. I also added "createdAt" as an attribute for faceting in algolia hmmm

Comment: I also just upgraded to `"react-instantsearch": "^4.2.0",` and still have this issue :/

Comment: Can you add the code of `<SearchHit/>`? It seems that the error is in the implementation of those modules.

Comment: Well the thing is I removed the `react-instantsearch` and reinstalled it, and now the error is gone, but I'm still not getting any results. No error, no results. I've even tried `<Configure filters="createdAt>=1501688239.446 AND createdAt<=1510132435.88" />` and still no results. What could I be missing?

Comment: Also, does the `createdAt` field need to be faceted or anything?

Comment: Not it does not but it needs to be an integer and not a string. Can you send a simple live example?

Comment: Hi, have you ever been able to implement this? I am working on something similar